# How to style an input that is a type="button"?

Tags: html, css, button, input

I am trying to make CSS changes a pop-up that basically is a centered div with a cookie policy and then an 'Accept' button. I am working with DNN CMS, and the pop-up is a module, so there is no way to change the div or class names.

The CSS works fine for the 'Accept' button, but then it affects the inputs for the Comment table. How do I write the CSS so that the CSS only affects the 'Accept' button in that div?

By the way, the 'Accept' button is an input that is type="button".

**HTML for 'Accept' button**

```
<input name="CookieConsent_CloseLink" id="View_CookieConsent_sal_CloseLink" value="Accept" type="button">
```

**CSS for 'Accept' button**

```
#View_CookieConsent_sal_CloseLink button, input {
font-family: 'Oswald', arial, sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 5px;
position: absolute;
left: 40%;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**HTML for 'Accept' button**

```
<input name="txtYourName" value="Anonymous" id="txtYourName" class="NormalTextBox" style="width: 100%" type="text">
```

Comment: Is there any other button around there? Otherwise, `input[type=button] { /* properties */ }` would work. If there are, `input[name=CookieConsent_CloseLink]` is more specific. Or you could just use the id if you know that it's not going to change.

Comment: You can target the input by attribute input[type=button]

Comment: Thanks both. input[type="button] fixed my problem.

Comment: Just use the id `#View_CookieConsent_sal_CloseLink` as selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input[type="button"] {
  font-family: 'Oswald', arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just want to target the first Accept button with type=button

```
#View_CookieConsent_sal_CloseLink {
....
}
```

should work

when you do #View_CookieConsent_sal_CloseLink button, you are targeting a button inside of that id. You can also target tags by attribute

```
input[type=button] { ....  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[The id would have to be unique in your page.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) I see that you have a `id="txtYourName"` generated. Use that.

```
#txtYourName{
   ...
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

instead of       #View_CookieConsent_sal_CloseLink button, input

use this          #txtYourName ,#View_CookieConsent_sal_CloseLink

So  CSS will fire button with id txtYourName 
and cookie with id  View_CookieConsent_sal_CloseLink

Good Luck